# Docker. Docker-Compose. Server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm kind of new to Docker. So, the project worked correctly, then I updated my ubuntu to 18.04. And now `docker-compose up` gives me this error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required`

Not sure what to try. Any advice will help.

Comment: More context please.

Comment: Looks like you will have to either configure PostgreSQL to support SSL encrypted connections or not require such connections on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a lot, a complete restart + this worked:

```
$ docker—compose down
$ docker—compose build
$ docker—compose up
```